# Do we need restclient in case if we have to support multiple plateform

Tags: java, rest

I've restful web service. I created a restful java client which can abstract connection details and expose beans to set the data. Now what happen if my web service has to be consumed by different platform than Java ? Wouldn't it had been better to avoid the client itself and let consumer make direct HTTP call ?

Comment: Whole point of REST is to be able to access any resource using HTTP protocol. You don't need to worry about the connection information, browsers or the callers will take care of it, unless you are expecting for a client proxy.

Comment: @Phani, Agrred but in case of SOAP, we just share wsdl and consumer generates client out of it based on their platform. This makes easier for developer to consume the service. But same is not with REST ?

Comment: No, observe the facebook REST API, A Restful Webservice is something where implementor hides the webservice complexities by a REST implementation so that you can call using simply with HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

WADL (https://wadl.java.net/) is the WSDL-equivalent for RESTful services, however, it is not very widely used by now.

Edit: A reason why it might be not popular can be found in this article: http://bitworking.org/news/193/Do-we-need-WADL

Comment: Would the down voter be so kind and explain why I got downvoted? See the comments, it is clearly what he looks for...

Comment: WADL is too complicated than SOAP, and the other thing is I don't see  a case where HTTP is language dependent. If we are talking about client proxies I would agree with you.

Comment: I think you got overrun by the level of English of the original poster, Pankaj does seem to talk about client proxies. Also "WADL is too complicated than SOAP" is comparing apples with bananas...please reconsider your downvote, thanks.

Comment: My bad.. Sorry.. I meant WSDL. WSDL is specification to discover and make use of services like the same as WADL. If @Pankaj agrees with Client proxies.. I will upvote your answer. If you read the reply from Pankaj in comments, you will see if he is talking about proxies still. We were talking in context, and I thought you made an assumption.

Comment: SOAP is no specification to discover services like WADL. WADL is no discovery specification either. WADL is the RESTful-world-equivalent of WSDL which *describes* services. Service discovery is done via UDDI in the SOAP-world.

Comment: I do understand, WADL could be one of the option. But I wanted to understand which is the best approach in terms of design ? IMO, it's about sharing contract definition of service vs sharing WADL. sorry, if my question was not clear.

Comment: WADL would allow generation of the clients, however, this is not the current custom. Instead, most API providers allow you to download a client-side library which is essentially nothing more than a thin-wrapper around JSON/XML results which are put into "data-holder-classes". A good example is indeed Facebook's REST API.